# Replacing in-page multi using Regex and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-frontend

I've shredded part of time with a subtitle file regex. I want to add html with Foreach to all returned values. Among values it adds html to the latest value.I want him to add to all of them.

example html:

```
<pre id="subtitle_txt">
1
00:00:00.05 -->; 00:00:03.02
Hello , Users.
2
00:00:03.02 -->; 00:00:05.00
Yep dude, it works successfully!
3
00:00:05.00 -->; 00:00:07.07
Have fun !
</pre>
```

jquery snippets:

```
   $('#subtitle_txt').text(data);
        const regex = /\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+ --> \d+:\d+:\d+.\d\d|[,\/]\d\d/g;
        let m;
        while ((m = regex.exec(data)) !== null) {
            if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++;
            }
            m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {

                $('#subtitle_txt').html($('#subtitle_txt').text().replace(match, '<x style="color:red">' + match + '</x>'));
                console.log(match);
            });
        }
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

I want all the time tags here to be red.

Comment: I didn't understand anything. Use https://jsfiddle.net/, Yusuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from a few minor things such as your text containing a semi-colon `-->;` so it doesn't match anything, the issue is this line:

```
$('#subtitle_txt').html($('#subtitle_txt').text().replace(
```

Where you read the existing value with `.text()` which removes any previously added html tags.

You can change this to read once / write once and it works fine:

```js
var data = $('#subtitle_txt').text();
const regex = /\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+ --> \d+:\d+:\d+.\d\d|[,\/]\d\d/g;
let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(data)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    data = data.replace(match, '<x style="color:red">' + match + '</x>');
    console.log(match);
  });
  $("#subtitle_txt").text(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="subtitle_txt">
1
00:00:00.05 --> 00:00:03.02
Hello , Users.
2
00:00:03.02 --> 00:00:05.00
Yep dude, it works successfully!
3
00:00:05.00 --> 00:00:07.07
Have fun !
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks you,working.I changed the last line. I want to add it as html. `$("#subtitle_txt").text(data); ` >  `$("#subtitle_txt").html(data); `